# pygame is not defined, now just a syntax error

Tags: pygame, nameerror

hope you guys can help. Initially the error raised by shell was 'nameError: 'pygame' is not defined', which seemed odd as without too great a change my code had previously ran fine. Now after fiddling with the code - commenting out lines, nothing too drastic - executing it from the python idle raises a basic syntax error. offending code:

```
pygame.display.update()
```

If this line is commented out, then a new syntax error is raised on the next line; offending code:

```
if isItSnap(middleDeck):
```

I looked at this post - ['pygame' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070277/pygame-is-not-defined) - but the answer did not apply.

Please let me know if i should post the whole program. pygame was of course imported and initialised.

```
#loop for actual gameplay
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #event.type, check identifier the 'type' of event it is
        #pygame.QUIT, all 'type's that an event can be are stored as constants
        #in pygame.locals module in fact the 'pygame' preceeding QUIT is unnecessary
        #QUIT is contant variable in pygame.locals module. now in our global namespace
        #finally to generate an event with type 'QUIT' user clicks red boxed cross on window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            terminate()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            terminate()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:#check
            if event.key == pygame.turnCardButton:#anyone can turn card over
                #lets us know user wants to flip card
                turnCard = True

    #turn card, only for computer atm
    if turnCard:
        turnCard(currentPlayer, middleDeck)
        turnCard = False

    #draw everything to screen, only need to blit latest card, no need whole screen
    #or draw everything end prog just draw the latest card here???
    windowSurface.fill(GREEN)#clear screen
    displayRect = windowSurface.get_rect()
    for cards in middleDeck:
        card = pygame.image.load(imageLocator[cards])
        #atm there is no rotation, all cards aligned perfectly
        windowSurface.blit(card, (displayRect.centerx - CARDX, displayRect.centery - CARDY)

    #update screen for user, this when they will try call snap
    pygame.display.update()

    if isItSnap(middleDeck):
        #need users to see card before we enter into loop
        #check rules snap, maybe need to timer if noone called can continue turning cards
        #clear event list as we want to find player with the QUICK DRAW YEEHAA
        pygame.event.clear()
        while True:
            #CURRENTLY NO SCORE CALLING SLOW IN PLAY
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    #who has one this round!?
                    if event.key == playerOneSnapButton:
                        #player one takes all the cards
                        player1 = middleDeck + player1
                        middleDeck = []
                        #just for now UNTIL ALL DRAWING HAS BEEN OPTIMIZED
                        windowSurface.fill(GREEN)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        break

                    elif event.key == playerTwoSnapButton:
                        player2 = middleDeck + player2
                        middleDeck = []
                        windowSurface.fill(GREEN)
                        pygame.display.update()
                        break                               
    else:
        time.sleep(playSpeed)#to slow game a little
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `)` in the previous line, `windowSurface.blit(card, (displayRect.centerx - CARDX, displayRect.centery - CARDY)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a typo. The closing parenthesis missing after

<s>`windowSurface.blit(card, (displayRect.centerx - CARDX, displayRect.centery - CARDY)`</s>

```py
windowSurface.blit(card, (displayRect.centerx - CARDX, displayRect.centery - CARDY))
```